# Waiting until an object is created

Tags: javascript, peerjs

I am connecting to peer.js and then assigning a property with the returned value. Currently I am using a timeout, but I was wondering if there is a way to just assign the property the value when it has been returned? Kind of how observables work.

```
this.peer = new Peer({ key: 'mykey' });
setTimeout(() => {
  this.myId = this.peer.id;
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? http://peerjs.com/docs/#peeron-open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the on open event like this

```
var peer = new Peer({ key: 'mykey' });
peer.on('open', function(id) {
  console.log('The ID is: ' + id);
});
```

Comment: I used () => to set the this.myId but otherwise thanks!